# Need formula to calculate tiered commissions, according to percentages

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vlookup, lookup

First off, I have looked everywhere, and every solution assumes that I'm working with dollar amounts, but my client works with percentages.  That being said, I need to figure out the formula to calculate tiered variable commissions.  I want to calculate the **Production $ Amount tiers** according to the user-entered Percent of Goal (the Actual Total Production $amt populates from this percentage), but I'm not having any luck.

[image: this screenshot]:

I need to calculate column E (outlined in red in the screenshot).  So far, for the first tier, I've got:

> `=IF(B9<B13,E11,C12*E11)`

**Edit**:
In answer to your questions:

> `B8 populates from another worksheet
>   B9 is the key variable
>   E11 =B8*B9
>   F11 =SUM(F12:F15)
>   F12 =E12*D12, F13 =E13*D13...`

I would like to use `LOOKUP` or `VLOOKUP` as explained [here] and [here].[2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fvSnFEsn_NI)

Comment: Sorry, I'm getting a bit lost in what does not work. Can you please [edit] your question and, based on the data in your screenshot, describe in plain words what you need to calculate? Use cell addresses like `A1` rather than concepts like `Profit`, so it is perfectly clear what your calculation elements are.

Comment: @teylyn I clarified a bit, I hope it helps.  I don't know why my links didn't work, so here they are again: [link 1](http://www.ozgrid.com/Excel/sliding-bracket.htm) [link 2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fvSnFEsn_NI)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming the total of the cells E12:E15 should be the $110,000 in your example. If you carried on with the formulas you had (starting with the 88,000 in E12), you'd be effectively allocating 121,000. My way you're assigning commission percentages to each part of the $110,000 sold according to the tiers you show.

[image: screen shot]

If the result you were looking for in your example is $17,400 in commissions, then here are the formulas for E12:E15...

```
E12: =MIN(C12,$B$9)*($E$11/$B$9)
E13: =MAX((MIN(C13,$B$9)-C12),0)*($E$11/$B$9)
E14:E15 (copy down from E13)
```

The min/max part of the formula is determining the percentage of quota for each tier (without going over the percentage of goal, B9) that applies to each tier. It then multiplies that by the total amount.